# Club multiple variable and get one output in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Club multiple variable and get one output in ansible
I will be using combined variable many other parts of the code and Is there a way to do it.

- name:

  hosts: dummy
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:

  - block:

## Capture package-Infra agent version

## v1

```
    - name: Get package-Integration agent version ostype1.4
      shell: command1
      register: NRAV1   
      when: ansible_distribution == "ostype" and ansible_distribution_version == "v1"     

    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ NRAV1 }}"
```

## v2

```
    - name: Get package-Integration agent version ostype2.2 
      shell: command2
      register: NRAV2                          
      when: ansible_distribution == "ostype" and ansible_distribution_version == "v2"   


    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ NRAV2 }}"
```

## v3

```
    - name: Get package-Integration agent version ostype2.3 
      shell: command3
      register: NRAV3  
      when: ansible_distribution == "ostype" and ansible_distribution_version == "v3"                            


    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ NRAV3 }}"


    - name: Result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ NRAV1.stdout | NRAV2.stdout | NRAV2.stdout }}"
```

#Output:

```
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [dummy]

TASK [Get package-Integration agent version ostype1.4] *************************
skipping: [dummy]

TASK [Debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [dummy] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed",
        "skipped": true
    }
}

TASK [Get package-Integration agent version ostype2.2] *************************
changed: [dummy]



TASK [Debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [dummy] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "rpm -qa --last | grep package-infra | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d'-' -f 3,4 | cut -d'.' -f 1,2,3,4,5",
        "delta": "0:00:00.524132",
        "end": "2021-03-07 12:06:33.150778",
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2021-03-07 12:06:32.626646",
        "stderr": "",
        "stdout": "1.15.1-1.ostype2.2",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "1.15.1-1.ostype2.2"
        ],
        "warnings": [
            "Consider using yum module rather than running rpm"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [Get package-Integration agent version ostype2.3] *************************
skipping: [dummy]

TASK [Debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [dummy] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed",
        "skipped": true
    }
}

TASK [Result] *******************************************************************
fatal: [dummy]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! template error while templating string: no filter named 'NRAV3.stdout'"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
dummy                : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

#My expected result would be >> NRAV2.stdout >> "1.15.1-1.ostype2.2"

Comment: Are you expecting `|` to perform a `or` between the three variables?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible is unable to parse below line -

```
msg: "{{ NRAV1.stdout | NRAV2.stdout | NRAV3.stdout }}"
```

You need to replace it with something like this -

```
msg: "{{ NRAV1.stdout }} | {{ NRAV2.stdout }} | {{ NRAV3.stdout }}"
```

Comment: `|` is the filter operator, it cannot be used inside `{{}}` for something else than filtering, that's why ansible is trying to find the filter 'NRAV3.stdout' but doesn't find any.